# I have array with arrays inside, this array has only 1 value. I would like to make it simple and convert to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert `[arr1, arr2, arr3]`, where `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3` are arrays containing the values `1`, `2` and `3` respectively, to the more simplified form `[1, 2, 3]`.

In particular, I am getting JSON data through an API and pushing values and creating and array to store them, like this:

```
let parentFolderids = []; // store their names within a local array
for(let i = 0; i < response.data.data.length; i++) {
    //const object = response.data.data[i];
    //console.log(object.parentIds[0])
    parentFolderids.push(response.data.data[i].parentIds);
}
```

Let's say the result of this is `parentFolderids` being, for example, `[ [12], [33], [22] ]`.

I want to convert it to simply `[12, 33, 22]`. How should I do it?

Comment: Can you use `array.flat()` or `[].concat(...array)`? I'm not sure I follow all of the details about the API and so forth. This question could just be "given an array `x`, how do I get `y`? and here's what I tried...", right? Can you show the original JSON response? Thanks.

Comment: I think i solve it just by adding .toString()    parentFolderids.push(response.data.data[i].parentIds.toString());

Comment: thanks ggorlen for tring to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bunch of different ways:

Using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (extracts only first element of each inner array; works on all modern browsers):

```js
const array = [[12], [33], [22], [77, 88, 99]];
const flat = array.map( x => x[0] );
console.log(flat);
```

Using [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (extracts *all* elements of each inner array; not supported on IE or Edge as of this writing*, polyfills available):

```js
const array = [[12], [33], [22], [77, 88, 99]];
const flat = array.flatMap( x => x );
console.log(flat);
```

Using [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) (same support limitations as above):

```js
const array = [[12], [33], [22], [77, 88, 99]];
const flat = array.flat(1);
console.log(flat);
```

Using [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (also not supported on IE / Edge*, polyfills not possible):

```js
const array = [[12], [33], [22], [77, 88, 99]];
const flat = [].concat(...array);
console.log(flat);
```

Using [`for`...`of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/for...of) loop and [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) (extracts only first element, works on every modern browser but not on IE):

```js
const array = [[12], [33], [22], [77, 88, 99]];
const flat = [];
for (const x of array) {
    flat.push( x[0] );
}
console.log(flat);
```

Using a plain old `for(;;)` loop and [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) (extracts only first element, works everywhere):

```js
const array = [[12], [33], [22], [77, 88, 99]];
const flat = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    flat.push( array[i][0] );
}
console.log(flat);
```

Using a plain old `for(;;)` loop with in-place modification (extracts only first element, modifies original array, works everywhere):

```js
const array = [[12], [33], [22], [77, 88, 99]];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i][0];
}
console.log(array);
```

I'm sure this is not an exhaustive list.

---

Ps. For your example code above, you might as well extract the parent IDs directly into a flat array, like this:

```
const parentFolderIds = response.data.data.map( x => x.parentIds[0] );
```

or (if you'd like all the parent IDs for each item, in case there are several):

```
const parentFolderIds = response.data.data.flatMap( x => x.parentIds );
```

or (if you prefer an explicit loop):

```
const parentFolderIds = [];
for (const x of response.data.data) {
    parentFolderIds.push( x.parentIds[0] );
}
```

or even just:

```
const data = response.data.data, parentFolderIds = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    parentFolderIds.push( data[i].parentIds[0] );
}
```

In any case, there's no point in first extracting them into a nested array and then flattening it, at least not unless you *also* need the nested array for something else.

---

<sup>*) The Edge 78.0 dev build seems to handle all of these fine, though — as one would expect, given that it's using the same JS engine as Chrome.</sup>

Comment: "polyfill" of `[].concat(...a)` spread syntax is `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], a)`

Comment: any solution touching `x[0]` where `x` is an array must also check `x.length > 0` otherwise `undefined` leaks into your program

Comment: @user633183: The OP specified that each inner array has exactly one element. If that assumption is _not_ actually always true, they will likely have bigger issues than the presence of a few `undefined` values in the array. (In particular, the various solutions I gave above will no longer all be equivalent, and the OP needs to decide how they actually want to handle cases where the inner array has more or less than one element. In some cases an `undefined` placeholder element might actually be exactly what's needed, but it's impossible to say if that's the case here without more context.)

Comment: i'm not saying your answer is wrong, i'm only alerting users of these programs that they will produce `undefined` in certain circumstances ^^

Comment: for consistency, i think `for (let x of array) ...` should be `for (const x of array) ...`. ie, use `let` only when the variable needs to be mutable, like in your `let i ... i++` examples.